# androidTest: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-testing, android-pendingintent, android-fragmentscenario

I'm trying to run launchFragmentInHiltContainer in androidTest source set.
Running below code fragment causes the mentioned in title error.

```
@Test
fun mainActivityTest(){
    val scenario = launchFragmentInHiltContainer<CoinInfoFragment> {  }
}
```

Function launchFragmentInHiltContainer:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    themeResId: Int = androidx.fragment.testing.R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme,
    fragmentFactory: FragmentFactory? = null,
    crossinline action: T.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val mainActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    ).putExtra(FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY, themeResId)

    ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(mainActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        fragmentFactory?.let {
            activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = it
        }
        val fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(T::class.java.classLoader),
            T::class.java.name
        )
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs

        activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
            .commitNow()

        (fragment as T).action()
    }

}
```

I was trying to resolve problem by solutions like:

- Android Lint : turn off Missing PendingIntent mutability,
- Adding:

```
    // Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.work:work-testing:$work_version"
```

Error stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.example.cointracker: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
    at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:406)
    at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:416)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:265)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:226)
    at com.example.cointracker.presentation.CoinsFragmentTest.mainActivityTest(CoinsFragmentTest.kt:116)
```

Nothing has helped. Do anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: Where is a PendingIntent initialized in your code? Can you provide it?

Comment: That's a good question, error is coming ActivityScenario placed in inlineFunction. I've edited question and added error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Update test.ext
add the line

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
```

if not present